# How to get a precise clock for midi/audio purpose

Tags: android, processing, midi

I'm trying to get a precise clock that is not influenced by other processes inside the app.

I currently use System.nanoTime() like below inside a thread.
I use to calculate the timing of each of the sixteen step.

Currently timed operations have sometime a perceptible delay that i try to fix.

I would like to know if there is a more precise way to obtaining timed operations, maybe by check the internal soundcard clock and use it to generate the timing i need.

I need it to send midi notes from android device to external audio sinthetizers and for audio i need precise timing

Is there anyone who can help me improve this aspect?

Thanks

```
cellLength = (long)(0.115*1000000000L);
for ( int x = 0; x < 16; x++ ) {
  noteStartTimes[x] = x*cellLength ;
}

long startTime = System.nanoTime();
index = 0;
while (isPlaying) {
  if (noteStartTimes[index] < System.nanoTime() - startTime) {
    index++ ;
    if (index == 16) { //reset things
      startTime = System.nanoTime() + cellLength;
      index = 0 ;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For any messages that you receive, the [`onSend` callback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/midi/MidiReceiver#onSend(byte[],%20int,%20int,%20long)) gives you a timestamp.
For any messages that you [send](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/midi/MidiReceiver#send(byte[],%20int,%20int,%20long)), you can provide a timestamp.

These timestamps are based on `System.nanoTime()`, so your own code should use this as well.

If your code is delayed (by its own processing, or by other apps, or by background services), `System.nanoTime()` will accurately report the delay. But no timer will function can make your code run earlier.

Comment: Thanks for help, i tried with timestamp, probably not enough but its don't working with all devices, only a few have timestamp compatibility, i have to more test about it.

Comment: I'm discovering the possibility of integrating C ++ to increase performance, 
Is it possible to rewrite this void as a C ++ library to increase the preformance?

Comment: Is it only *your* code that causes the delays? Anyway, that would be a different question.